# How to submit Binary review for Facebook SDK Developer

Tags: ios, facebook

I'm using special permission "Tagged_friend" on new Facebook SDK.

I have some questions about the review process:

1. In the review form, there is a section "Upload your app". Because now it not allows to get tagged_friends so what exactly that Facebook will review?
2. How long is the review?

Answer (score 0):

1. The review will see if your app actually works and what functionality you provide. If you request 'tagged_friends' but don't use it in your app, you don't get the permission. This is to prevent apps from collecting data without providing an user experience for it.
2. It can take up to a few days, but in general it's pretty quick. Since a lot of apps are now submitting for review, due to the April 30 change, it might take a bit longer.

Comment: I mean now I use facebook sdk request tagged_fiends, but it not allow so it return no data at all, so how can I show it to facebook. My app automatically requests data and shows on GUI, if no data, it shows nothing. So how can facebook knows when reviewing the binary. It's quite annoy

Comment: You can use the permission with user accounts that are Admins or Developers, or with Test Users. You can use those accounts to make your screenshots. When the reviewing team logins, they can accept the permissions you request for that session, to test it.